# MessageBox keeps appearing in my window form in Visual Studio 2012..?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

Just a little background: I'm creating a room management system with different windows forms in Visual Studios. I made the login window and three other windows. Once a user logs in with either a STUDENT, FACULTY, or JANITOR username, it takes them to that one particular windows form.

Everything works great and logs in based on which user but, I keep getting my MessageBox which is suppose to only pop up once someone enters the wrong username/password! I don't have any errors so I don't know how to go about fixing this.

Here's just the code with my login windows form which has the messagebox:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace LOGINPAGE
{
    public partial class Room : Form
    {
        public Room()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PassText.PasswordChar = '*';
        }
        private void xButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Mohamed\Documents\UserData.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count (*) From dbo.[LOGIN] where username='" + UserText.Text + "' and Password ='" + PassText.Text + "'", con);
            FloorSelection ss = new FloorSelection();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
            {
                SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter("Select TYPE From dbo.[LOGIN] where username='" + UserText.Text + "' and Password ='"
                    + PassText.Text + "'", con);
                FloorSelection ss1 = new FloorSelection();
                DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                sda1.Fill(dt1);

                if (dt1.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "FACULTY")
                {
                    this.Hide();
                    FACULTY ff = new FACULTY();
                    ff.Show();
                }
                if (dt1.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "STUDENT")
                {
                    this.Hide();
                    STUDENT st = new STUDENT();
                    st.Show();


                }
                if (dt1.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "JANITOR")
                {
                    this.Hide();
                    JANITOR jt = new JANITOR();
                    jt.Show();

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("PLEASE CHECK YOUR USERNAME AND PASSWORD");

                }
            }
        }


        private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label3.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        }

        private void UserText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of the Condition you ware given. You will get the msgbox all time when `if (dt1.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "JANITOR")` evaluates to false. so the best option here is `if..elseif..else`; So the snippet will be like the following:

```
       if (dt1.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "FACULTY")
        {
            //statements
        }
        else if (dt1.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "STUDENT")
        {
            //statements
        }
        else if (dt1.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "JANITOR")
        {
            //statements
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("PLEASE CHECK YOUR USERNAME AND PASSWORD");
        }
```

So the `else` part will execute only when all the above condition is false.

Comment: Well, that solved my message popup but now it won't come up on incorrect entries lol

Comment: what you mean by incorrect entries? please check whether `dt1` has rows or not

Answer (score 2):

Your `else` clause only match your last `if` clause. So if the last condition is false it will execute the method on the `else` clause. User `if/else if` to solve it:

```
            if (dt1.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "FACULTY")
            {
                this.Hide();
                FACULTY ff = new FACULTY();
                ff.Show();
            } else if (dt1.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "STUDENT")
            {
                this.Hide();
                STUDENT st = new STUDENT();
                st.Show();
            } else if (dt1.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "JANITOR")
            {
                this.Hide();
                JANITOR jt = new JANITOR();
                jt.Show();
            } else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("PLEASE CHECK YOUR USERNAME AND PASSWORD");
            }
```

Comment: Well, that solved my message popup but now it won't come up on incorrect entries lol

Comment: Have you debugged it?

Comment: Yeah, now there's no messagebox at all when someone enters wrong info

Comment: Umm, it should enter at least one condition. If the info is wrong it just skips the `else` part?

Answer (score 0):

I think you intent to use else if, it will always show the Message unless "JANITOR". because the following block. You should use swith case, or else if for condition checks.

```
            if (dt1.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "JANITOR")
            {
                this.Hide();
                JANITOR jt = new JANITOR();
                jt.Show();

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("PLEASE CHECK YOUR USERNAME AND PASSWORD");

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Switch case statement and see whether error persist or not.